# How to monitor temperature of an area?

Tags: sensor, measurement

What is the proper non-contact way to monitor the temperature of an surface area? In the picture below, I divided a square into 36 little squares. The goal is to get the temperature of each and everyone of little squares. What technique do you recommend?

The most obvious one is to attach 36 laser thermometers, but this approach doesn't scale well, if the number of squares becomes larger, or the size of them smaller.

Edit:

- Each square's area is about 0.25cm2
- Material isn't fixed. It ranges from metals to organic.
- I have no clue of the emissivity of the materials in question and it would also be hard to predict all of them.
- Desired sampling frequency is 1Hz for the whole surface so read time I guess is < 1s/36 per square for the particular image and more like 10ms for each of 100 minisquares, but the exact value doesn't matter
- Desired temperature range falls within 300K and 600K

  [image]

Comment: Incremental positioning of mirror ?  or Lens

Comment: Microbolometer array?

Comment: Your question is poor. (1) How big is your "little"? (2) What is the material? (3) What is its surface emissivity (for infra-red radiation)? (4) What is the required read time and frequency? Put all the information **in your question**.

Comment: I have an evaluation kit for this very purpose at work. Range and accuracy was a bit limited though. What are your requirements?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: For non-contact you MUST know the emmisivity. I think you are going to want to use a thermal imaging solution. Maybe you could use a single contact probe on one of the squares. By knowing the actual temperature there, you could deduce the unknown emissivity.

Answer (score 2):

Buy FLIR camera. If you have to develop it by yourself, it sshould be something like mems mirror and a single sensor, so the system would scan the area.